# SQL Server collation mismatch

Tags: sql-server, collation

I have database server with collation: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

I got database backup file which collation is: `Latin1_General_CI_AS`

When I'm restoring this database and executing some SQL, I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation
```

I've changed database collation to match:

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

And now getting even more this kind of errors.

Is there any common way to modify all database object collation to prevent this kind of issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have change all user tables and columns individually, droppng and creating all constraints as needed. [It's straightforward, just tedious.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2938422/27535) (SO link)

You can also use COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT to coerce collations in code without actually knowing what one is used.

Comment: In my case I was using stored procedures with temp table declaration. Defining colums added COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT and it worked. Thank you